# Update query not working in PHP and Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have made an update page which fetches record from a table, shows all the details on html form where user can change/Edit the values and submit. Next page fetches those values using $_POST and Update the table.

```
$new_id = $_POST['c_id'];
$new_name = $_POST['c_name'];
$table_name = "tcompany";

$sqlStatement = "UPDATE $table_name SET 'name'=$new_name WHERE 'id'= $new_id";
if($result_1 = mysql_query($sqlStatement)) 
{
    header('Location: edit_company.php');
}
else {
        echo "". mysql_error();
}
```

I am getting error  :
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''name'=HARDWARE Exporters WHERE 'id'= 69' at line 1

I am not considering security issues related to injection. Using this code for personal use.

Answer (score 6):

Don't use apostrophe (`'`) for column names and use it instead to your variables.

```
$sqlStatement = "UPDATE ".$table_name." SET name='$new_name' WHERE id='$new_id'";
```

You should also sanitize the values you are binding to your query. Use `*_real_escape_string`.

```
$new_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["c_id"]);
```

And `mysql_*` API is already [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php) and you should consider using [mysqli prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) instead.

If you want an example of prepared statement, using the code you have given, you can refer below. No need to sanitize each values before using them to your query.

```
/* ESTABLISH FIRST YOUR CONNECTION */
$con = new mysqli("YourHost","Username","Password","Database"); /* REPLACE NECESSARY DATA */

if($stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE ? SET name = ? WHERE id = ?")){ /* CHECK IF STATEMENT IS TRUE */
  $stmt->bind_param("ssi",$table_name,$_POST["c_name"],$_POST["c_id"]); /* BIND VALUES TO YOUR QUERY */
  $stmt->execute(); /* EXECUTE THE QUERY */
  $stmt->close();
} /* END OF PREPARED STATEMENT */
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that **variable `$new_name` contains spaces**. So you should quote the use of variables in the statement, like this:

```
$sqlStatement = "UPDATE $table_name SET 'name'='$new_name' WHERE 'id'= '$new_id'";
```